# jira logging finish time (not time spent)

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

After finishing some task, how is it possible in jira log this current(finish) time? 
So I don't want calculate time spending on task as start time of task + time spended on task, I want only enter finish time and time spent will be calculated(in jira) as finish time-start time.

Answer (score 0):

JIRA doesn't currently offer real-time time tracking.

However your IDE should have some means of logging you time - for example Eclipse has this built in in the tasks plugin and it could also be connected to JIRa so that you could see your tasks in the IDE and log your time in "real-time" right there.

I have found this to be rather inconvenient since if inactive inside the IDE for a certain period of time the tracking will stop - this is an option in the IDE though.
I personally use [Toggl](http://www.toggl.com) which is free for a "one-man show" team. Also their pricing for teams is very nice. There are other services like Toggl and they are not all web-based. For example [Project Hamster](http://projecthamster.wordpress.com/) if you're on Linux. Just google `time tracking`. ;) Otherwise as I said the only way is to connect your IDE to JIRA via some task module.